# Duplicate results with SQL Query join between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join 2 tables with the following query:

```sql
SELECT board.boardID, board.userID, board.postID, items.Url, 
items.Image
FROM board 
JOIN items on userID = items.user_id
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image: Database]

However, as you can see, every result is printed double. I tried using SELECT DISTINCT but that is giving the same result.

Comment: I see no duplicates in your rows.  So, I'm not sure what you want as the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake,

The query I was looking for is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT board.boardID, board.userID, board.postID, items.Url, 
items.Image
FROM board 
JOIN items on postID = items.id
```

I joined the items table on the wrong id :)